# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.PersistenceContext.synchronization

Tags: java, spring, jpa, tomcat, eclipselink

While deploying application on Tomcat 8.0.36 I am getting following exception

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'eventsDAOImpl' Post-processing of merged bean
>   definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceContext.synchronization()Ljavax/persistence/SynchronizationType;
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:756)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:409)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4842)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1816)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) **Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceContext.synchronization()Ljavax/persistence/SynchronizationType;**
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:653)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.lambda$buildPersistenceMetadata$0(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:416)
>     at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalFields(ReflectionUtils.java:693)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:410)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:394)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:332)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1015)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
>     ... 24 more

I am using eclipselink version 2.5.2 and added following jars in the lib folder of tomcat

1. eclipselink-2.5.2.jar
2. javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar
3. ojdbc6-12.1.0.1.jar

dependencies.gradle is as follows

```
compile (
        'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.4',
        'org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.4',
        'org.springframework:spring-aspects:5.0.0.RELEASE',
        'org.springframework:spring-jdbc:5.0.0.RELEASE',
        'org.springframework:spring-jms:5.0.0.RELEASE',
        'org.springframework:spring-orm:5.0.0.RELEASE',
        'org.springframework:spring-oxm:5.0.0.RELEASE',
        'org.springframework:spring-web:5.0.0.RELEASE',
        'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:5.0.0.RELEASE',
        'org.springframework:spring-instrument-tomcat:4.0.9.RELEASE'
    }
    provided (
        'com.oracle:ojdbc6:12.1.0.1',
        'org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:2.5.2'
    )
```

**Edit 1** :  Same application is running fine on Tomcat 9 but giving above exception while deploying on Tomcat 8

**Edit 2** :  After doing some research I found out that Tomcat 8 is loading PersistenceContext class from annotations-api.jar located in TOMCAT_HOME\lib folder instead of javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar and PersistenceContext  class available in annotations-api.jar does not contain synchronization method as follows.

```
package javax.persistence;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface PersistenceContext {
  String name() default "";

  String unitName() default "";

  PersistenceContextType type() default PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION;

  PersistenceProperty[] properties() default {};
}
```

How to give preference in Tomcat 8 such that Tomcat 8 will load PersistenceContext class from javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar instead of annotations-api.jar

Comment: javax.persistence.PersistenceContext.synchronization() returns javax.persistence.SynchronizationType which was only added in JPA 2.1 so you must have the earlier persistence-api jar in the container in a way that the class loader is finding and using it instead of your 2.2 version.

Comment: Chris thanks for help I have updated the question . Kindly see the edit 2 part of my question

Answer (score 1):

may be you are having conflicts in your spring data dependency version One is vesion1 (or replication of two same jar you can say)another is version2 Please remove older version dependency either version one or version two from pom.xml or from build path jar

OR

may be there is no Spring data jar or dependency over there please kindly add it.

Comment: Same  application is running fine on Tomcat 9

Answer (score 0):

org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:1.0.1.Finals delivers an OLD version of javax.persistance that lack of that API PersitanceContext().synchronization()

Solution: add java.persistence:javax.persistence-api:2.2 BEFORE hibernate-jpa-2.0-api in the **pom.xml**

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

No idea about gradle, but at least you can try.

Answer (score -1):

I see `PersistenceContext.class` with the `synchronization()` method in `javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar`. It looks like Apache has removed `PersistenceContext` (along with other classes) from `annotations-api.jar` as of Tomcat 7 which means it can't be loading this class from the Tomcat provided jar.  Perhaps you have a another jar in your application that has an old version of `PersistenceContext` in it?

Comment: I had the same idea and added java.persistence:javax.persistence-api:2.2 to the pom.xml but NOTHING CHANGED. Later I instrument to print the resource path for the PersistenceContext and both where loaded from org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:1.0.1.Fiinals